# how to adjust padding between paragraphs in xml data using action script 3..?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs4

Its me again come up with another question, how to adjust padding between each paragraphs in AS3..? Actually  I'll show you an example that I've coded now.

```
style.setStyle(".readmore", {fontWeight:"normal", color:"#6184b7", fontSize:11});
style.setStyle("body", {fontStyle:"italic"});
```

like the code above I want to set a 5px padding-bottom for `<p>` tag, now it is 10px default.

Is that possible..? If yes how to write that single line code..?

Thanks in advance!

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution is to add fake tags inside `TextField.htmlText`  :

Instead of

```
textField.htmlText = "<p>Some text [...] here</p><p>Some text [...] here</p>"
```

Do that:

```
textField.htmlText = "<p>Some text [...] here</p><font size='2'><br></font></p><p>Some text [...] here</p>"
```

You can do it automatically for each paragraphs:

```
textField.htmlText = content.replace("</p>", "</p><font size='5'><br></font>");
```

It will insert margin after all paragraphs.
Change to a greater size if you want more space.

Comment: Mems, Im sorry for the late reply, anyway thanks a lot for your answer!